Filling a C# array
I need to fill a 2 dimensional array, however in need to the 2 outermost sides to be filled with ones and the rest with zeros.
11111111111111111111
11111111111111111111
11000000000000000011
11000000000000000011
11000000000000000011
11000000000000000011
11000000000000000011
11000000000000000011
11111111111111111111
11111111111111111111

Like this. How can I set up a loop for this?
I have tried looping it myself, but I am not the best with 2d arrays.

Can you fill it with just 1's? Do you have some code?

Two ways - you can loop and fill each row with 1 using a library fill method, then loop from x=2 to x < length - 2 (same for y) and put 0 in there. The other is to loop through x and y, and for each element use a test (e.g. x > 1 && x < length - 2, same for y) to determine whether to put a 1 or 0 there.

You'd have to loop over both indices in a nested loop and set the values to either 1 or 0, based on if either index < 2 or either index >= length - 2:
int[,] array = new int[20,10];

for (int x = 0; x < array.GetLength(0); x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < array.GetLength(1); y++) {
        if (x < 2 || x >= array.GetLength(0)-2 || y < 2 || y >= array.GetLength(1)-2) {
            array[x,y] = 1;
        } else {
            array[x,y] = 0;
        }
    }
}

We use array.GetLength(0) here instead of array.Length since GetLength length of each axis' dimension, while array.Length would return the total number of elements (200, 20x10), looping too many times.
If you just created a new int array, they're filled with 0s by default, so you can just focus on setting the 1s in that case.

You need two for loops to accomplish the above task.

One to loop through the rows
Second to loop through the columns

While doing so you can check if it is a boundary or not via a if condition.
Refer to the boundary checking if condition on the solution below.
Once after assigning respective 1 and 0 to the matrix. Use another two for loops to print the values accordingly.

Refer to the working .netfiddle here

Refer to the code below for more reference:
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int rows = 9; // define number of rows here
        int cols = 20; // define number of columns here

        int[,] matrix = new int[rows, cols];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                if (i == 0 || i == rows - 1 || j == 0 || j == cols - 1) // check if it is boundry 
                {

                    matrix[i, j] = 1; // Set the value to 1 for the outermost sides
                }
                else
                {

                    matrix[i, j] = 0; // Set the value to 0 for all other positions
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) // for rows iteration
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) // for column iteration
            {
                Console.Write(matrix[i, j]); // Print values
            }
            Console.WriteLine(); // Print new line
        }

    }
}

Sample output:

